# Broken/missing handler error for my custom views filter?

Tags: views, 8

I am trying to write a custom filter for views. The goal is to filter by alias, but that's not important now. It seems like I am missing a step to get view to recognize my filter hander after adding my filter in `hook_views_data_alter` as in the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function alias_views_filter_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['node']['alias'] = [
    'title' => t('alias filter'),
    'filter' => [
      'title' => t('alias filter'),
      'help' => t('Provides a custom filter nodes by their alias.'),
      'field' => 'nid',
      'id' => 'entity_alias',
    ],
  ];
}
```

I am able to get the filter to show in a view filter list.
Now, my filter handler defined in `/docroot/modules/custom/alias_views_filter/Plugin/views/filter/Alias.php` but it does not seem to be picked up by views and I always get `Broken/missing handler` whenever I try to add the filter. Here is my handler definition:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\alias_views_filter\Plugin\views\filter;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\StringFilter;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


/**
 * Filters by alias.
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("entity_alias")
 */
class Alias extends StringFilter {



  /**
   * The current display.
   *
   * @var string
   *   The current display of the view.
   */
  protected $currentDisplay;

  /**
   * @var views_plugin_query_default
   */
  public $query;

  /**
   * Constructs a new StringFilter object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection $connection
   *   The database connection.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, Connection $connection) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    // this does seem to get evaluated at all ?
    die('Death in handler');
  }

  protected function defineOptions() {
    $options = parent::defineOptions();
    $options['fields'] = ['default' => []];

    return $options;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
    parent::init($view, $display, $options);
    $this->valueTitle = t('Filter by alias');
  }

  public function buildOptionsForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::buildOptionsForm($form, $form_state);
    $this->view->initStyle();
  }

  function query() {
    $this->ensureMyTable();
    $field = $this->tableAlias."nid"; //table_alias.".nid";
    $nids = $this->getNidsByAliasString($this->value);
    if (!empty($nids)) {
      $this->query->addWhere('AND', $this->options['group'], $field, $nids, 'IN');
    }
  }

  function getNidsByAliasString($aliasString) {
    $query = db_select('url_alias');
    $query->condition('alias', '%'.$aliasString.'%', 'LIKE');
    $result = $query
      ->fields('url_alias')
      ->execute();

    $nids = array();
    foreach ($result as $data) {
      array_push($nids, end(explode("/",$data->source)));
    }
    return $nids;
  }

}
```

Am missing a step or naming the filter incorrectly?

Checking the logs,  I am getting these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: field in Drupal\views\Plugin\ViewsHandlerManager->getHandler() 
Notice: Undefined index: table in Drupal\views\Plugin\ViewsHandlerManager->getHandler() 
Notice: Undefined index: id in Drupal\views\Plugin\ViewsHandlerManager->getHandler()
```

Comment: I believe this line is wrong: '$this->query->addWhere('AND', $this->options['group'], $field, $nids, 'IN');' as the addWhere only accepts 4 parameters, I see 5 parameters in there.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the data table instead of the base table, just replace node with node_field_data in your hook and run drush cr.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function alias_views_filter_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['node_field_data']['alias'] = [
    'title' => t('alias filter'),
    'filter' => [
      'title' => t('alias filter'),
      'help' => t('Provides a custom filter nodes by their alias.'),
      'field' => 'nid',
      'id' => 'entity_alias',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: I tried with both but it does not seem that's the issue. In fact initially wrote my question with `node_field_data` then edited it.